# Creating nullable class

Tags: c#

How do I create a nullable (`?`) class in C#? Like:

```
public class Hello1 {
  public int Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Hello2 {
 Public Hello1? Property2 { get; set; } //Hello1 should work when it has "?"
}
```

I want to make `Hello1` class to be able to take the form `Hello1?` if needed.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You don't need to create a nullable type for reference types.  They're already nullable.  You only need to do this for Value types like int, bool, decimal, etc...

Comment: Ok I was confusing the KeyValuePair with a class. It was a struct so it required "?". I was trying to create the same thing. It makes sense.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to; reference types can already be `null`. As for structures, simply appending a `?` *will* work. So just remove the `?`, and check for `null` using `== null`, as usual.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the questionmark. All classes are nullable by default. Only value-type objects (like struct) need to be explicitly made nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful of the fact that class references will not be nullable starting C# v8 (Visual Studio 2019). Now we've new `ClassName?` syntax. This `?` suffix denotes the fact explicitly that the given variable can hold null value. Without the `?` suffix the variable becomes a non-nullable reference type. In such a case compiler will start issuing warning/error depending upon your IDE settings. So going forward something like this:

```
string empName = null;
```

will issue warning like this:

> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

To get rid of the warning declare your variable like this:

```
string? empName = null;
```

You can read about this feature here - [Nullable reference types in C# v8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)

Answer (score 1):

All classes are nullable. nullable is for Value types that can't be null

Answer (score 0):

`Hello1` is nullable already.  You don't need the `?` on your property.

**Edit** - I suspect you might be trying to set `Hello1.Property1` to null, and you're hoping that making `Hello1` nullable will allow that.  It won't.  You need to mark `Property1` as nullable if you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

`Hello1` is already a reference type, so it can be `null` already.
 The nullable syntax "classname?" can only be applied to ValueTypes, such as `int`, `DateTime`, `float` etc., which can not be `null` usually.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember, there are two kind of datatypes in C# or any programming language, namely Value Types (e.g. int, float, bool) and Reference Types (all the user defined classes and string data type).

Value Types get a memory location assigned as soon as they are created. So they must hold a value, whereas reference type only get hold of a memory location when they are explicitly created using the `new` keyword.

So all reference types are nullable by-default as long as they are not referring a memory location. And we can always assign them `null`.

To make Value Types nullable, we create a wrapper around existing value type by appending a question mark `?` next to it. This way a Value Type becomes nullable in C#.